# Google isn't indexing AJAX URLs even after fetching them with _escaped_fragment

Tags: url, googlebot, apache-log-files

I'm still in the process of making my site crawlable through Google even though it's all AJAX content. I got it where if the URL contains `escaped_fragment_` it retrieves the right information form the PHP files.

Googlebot is regularly requesting these fragments from my server so it appears that's going well, but still none are indexed. I think it's because its still deeming `www.foo.net/#!1` is the same site as `www.foo.net/`, so it's not indexing everything else.

I tried looking at my server logs and I don't quite understand them. Why does the bottom line not have a referring URL and if it sees the URL as `escaped_fragment_` does that mean it knows that it isn't the same as the index home page?

[image: log file]

Answer (score 1):

A really simple way to get them indexed would be to create a google webmaster tools account, claim your domain and then submit a complete sitemap. Depending on the authority of your site, Google is going to make resource decisions about how much effort to put into spidering your site.